# Losing Data on Reload When Fetching Data from a Service in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I am using a service to send two lists of objects between two Angular pages, which works correctly. The problem is, if I happen to reload the page that recieves the data, the lists will get deleted from memory.
Is there a way to avoid this problem?

The way I am sending the data is simply by having two lists in the service defined as global variables, and I assign them the values of the two lists in page 1 before navigating to page 2. Once I'm in page two, I simply fetch the service on the OnInit method and assign the lists to the ones on page 2. Is there a way to persist this data after a reload?

Comment: its called state, and its a broad topic on web development. I'd start my way with googling `sessionStorage` and move on from there

Comment: thanks, I'm new on this, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Put this to the place where you get the data:

```
localStorage.setItem('theKeyYouWant', JSON.stringify(this.list));
```

Put this to the ngOnInit:

```
const item = localStorage.getItem('theKeyYouWant');
if (item) {
    this.list = JSON.parse(item);
} else {
    this.list = [];
}
```

See: [MDN localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

localStorage exists in the browser, there is no need to import something.

I often use this code in my projects:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export class TypedDataService<T> {
  private readonly bhs: BehaviorSubject<T> = new BehaviorSubject<T>(null);
  valueChanges$ = this.bhs.asObservable();
  private value: T;

  constructor(
    private readonly key: string,
    private readonly defaultValue: T = null,
    private readonly equals: (x: T, y: T) => boolean = (x: T, y: T) =>
      JSON.stringify(x) === JSON.stringify(y),
    private readonly clone: (x: T) => T = (x: T) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x)),
    private readonly parse: (s: string) => T = (s: string) => JSON.parse(s) as T,
    private readonly stringify: (x: T) => string = (x: T) => JSON.stringify(x)
  ) {
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    const item = localStorage.getItem(this.key);
    if (item) {
      this.value = this.parse(item);
    } else {
      this.value = this.defaultValue;
    }
    if (this.value) {
      this.next();
    }
  }

  update(nvObj: T) {
    if (!this.equals(nvObj, this.value)) {
      if (nvObj === null) {
        localStorage.removeItem(this.key);

      } else {
        this.value = this.parse(this.stringify(nvObj));
        const nv = this.stringify(nvObj);
        localStorage.setItem(this.key, nv);
      }
      this.next();
    }
  }

  getValue(): T {
    return this.value;
  }

  private next() {
    this.bhs.next(this.clone(this.value));
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SettingsData } from '../data/settings.data';
import { TypedDataService } from '../../common/typed-data-service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SettingsService {
  private static readonly innerService = new TypedDataService<SettingsData>(
    'settings',
    new SettingsData()
  );

  get settings$() {
    return SettingsService.innerService.valueChanges$;
  }

  getSettingsFromStorage(): SettingsData {
    return SettingsService.innerService.getValue();
  }

  settings2storage(data: SettingsData): void {
    SettingsService.innerService.update(data);
  }

  private deleteSettingsFromStorage(): void {
    SettingsService.innerService.update(null);
  }
}
```